# Building XML document in lowercase or TitleCase - flag based

Tags: java, xml, enums, constants

In my current project, we are in the process of re-factoring a java class that constructs an XML document. In previous versions of the product delivered to the customer, the XML document is built with lower case elements and attributes:

```
<rootElement attr = "abc">
    <childElement childAttr = "xyz"/>
</rootElement>
```

But now we have a requirement to build the XML document with TitleCase element and attributes. The user will set a flag in a properties file to indicate whether the document should be built in lower case or title case. If the flag is configured to build the document in TitleCase, the resultant document will look like:

```
<RootElement Attr = "abc">
    <ChildElement ChildAttr = "xyz">
</RootElement>
```

Various approaches to solve the problem: 
1. Plugging in a transformer to convert lowercase XML document to TitleCase XML document. But this will impact the overall performance, as we deal with huge XML files spanning more than 10,000 lines. 
2. Create two separate maps with corr. XML elements and attributes.
For eg:
`lowercase map: rootelement -> rootElement, attr -> attr ....` 
`TitelCase map: rootlement -> RootElement, attr -> Attr ....` 
Based on the property set by the user, the corr. map will be chosen and XML element/attributes from this map will be used to build the XML document.
3. Using enum to define constants and its corr. values.

```
public enum XMLConstants {
    ROOTELEMENT("rootElement", "RootElement"),
    ATTRIBUTE("attr", "Attr");

    private String lowerCase;
    private String titleCase;

    private XMLConstants(String aLowerCase, String aTitleCase){
        titleCase = aTitleCase;
        lowerCase = aLowerCase;
    }

    public String getValue(boolean isLowerCase){
        if(isLowerCase){
            return lowerCase;
        } else {
            return titleCase;
        }
    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------

// XML document builder

if(propertyFlag){
    isLowerCase = false;
} else {
    isLowerCase = true;
}

....
....

createRootElement(ROOTELEMENT.getValue(isLowerCase));
createAttribute(ATTRIBUTE.getValue(isLowerCase));
```

Please help me choose the right option keeping in mind the performance aspect of the entire solution. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you make all your tags/attributes lowercased? Then your XML file can contain lowercase, titlecase, upercased or any other form - and you'll be able to read the XML-file anyway

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, we are not in a position to do so. Customers are already making use of this product and are consuming the lower case XML document. So we need to ensure the current changes are backward compatible. The requirement to build TitleCase XML document is to integrate our system with a legacy system that expects the XML to be fed in TitleCase.

Comment: Sure, That'll make that able. Whenever you parse an XML-tag or Attribute, call `String.toLower()` and then compare it with the lower cased version of your tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// set before generate XML
boolean isUpperCase;

// use function for each tag/attribute name instead of string constant
// smth. like getInCase("rootElement")
String getInCase(String initialName) {
    String intialFirstCharacter = initialName.substring(0, 1);
    String actualFirstCharacter;
    if (isUpperCase) {
        actualFirstCharacter = intialFirstCharacter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        actualFirstCharacter = intialFirstCharacter.toLowerCase();
    }
    return actualFirstCharacter + initialName.substring(1);

}
```